# renderPlot outputs plot in View, not browser

Tags: r, shiny

My goal is to plot the output, a process map, onto the browser. The output plot continues to appear in the Viewer pane in RStudio.

All of the functionality works as expected and I'm able to call the appropriate data and generate a dynamic output based on the dropdown menu.

Any help would be much appreciated. Full code is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(bupaR)
library(pm4py)
library(reticulate)
library(processmapR)
        
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$h1("Process Mining"),

  tags$p("The purpose of this application is to show the Process Map output"),

  fluidRow(
    selectInput("pm_type","Process Mining Type", c("absolute","relative"))),
  
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput("plot1"))
  )

  

server <- function(input, output) {

  selectedData <- reactive({input$pm_type}) 
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    patients %>% 
      process_map(type = frequency(selectedData()))
    
  })     
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you, Ronak!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get output of `process_map` in `shiny` you have to use GrViz functions from `DiagrammeR`.

```
library(shiny)
library(bupaR)
library(pm4py)
library(reticulate)
library(processmapR)
library(DiagrammeR)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Process Mining"),
  tags$p("The purpose of this application is to show the Process Map output"),
  fluidRow(
    selectInput("pm_type","Process Mining Type", c("absolute","relative"))),
  fluidRow(
    grVizOutput("plot1"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  selectedData <- reactive({input$pm_type}) 
  output$plot1 <- renderGrViz({
    patients %>% 
      process_map(type = frequency(selectedData()))
  })     
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]